# Read NFC tag and write it on HTML form

Tags: forms, nfc

Is there any possible way to read the "Read only" NFC data and Write it on HTML form?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Android or IOS we can Read NFC Data

for Android please check with following link

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc

For IOS Please check with following link

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/building_an_nfc_tag-reader_app

For Android Chrome web

https://web.dev/nfc/